# Calibrating the axes of a 2D plot

Tags: plotting, labeling

When the data

```
a = Table[Sin[x], {x, 1, 20, 0.1}];
ListPlot[0.1 *a]
```

is plotted, one finds that the range of x-axes is labeled as 0 to 200:

[image]

How can one reset the calibration so that the axis shows the range only up to 20?

Comment: You have 200 data points, and so `ListPlot` gives you that axis. You want to have 2D points: `ListPlot[Transpose[{Range[1, 20, .1], a}]]`. This gives you a list of {x, y} pairs instead of a single list of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`DataRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange) option:

```
ListPlot[0.1 a, DataRange -> {1, 20}]
```

[image]